# TextViews alignment with dynamic content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

Current view:
[image]

This is the expected result:
[image]

The thing is that the red text is dynamic I don't know the length until run-time.

Currently I have a `LinearLayout` and in it I have two `TextViews` one for the red text and another for the clickable link. I have managed to display the link below the red text with `LinearLayout android:orientation=vertical`.

If I set it to `android:orientation=horizontal` the link goes to the far right not next to the content of the red text.

My Current XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_container_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_container_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/card_container_padding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cms_message_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/body_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text=""/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cms_message_modal_link"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_home_line_margin_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/lightBlue"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/body_text_size"
            android:text="More Info"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Should I use a different layout or is there an attribute that can help me?

Comment: The problem is that you're using `LinearLayout` with an `orientation` set to `vertical` meaning all your elements will stack vertically. You can use a `RelativeLayout` to set the second `TextView` to be next to the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Xan's answer isn't wrong for display purposes it doesn't allow only the underline portion to be clicked. I suggest using:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cms_message_content);
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Here is some non linked text, but this is linked");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey you clicked me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
int indexOfComma = ss.toString().indexOf(","); /* just for this case, im coloring after the comma */
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, indexOfComma + 1, ss.toString().length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only 1 TextView and setText using Spannable

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

```
Spannable text = new SpannableString("This is underline and bold text.");
text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 8, 17, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 22, 26, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setText(text);
```